# Size of information in last fread() in C

Tags: c, fread

```
#define MAXSIZE 256

fread(buff, sizeof(MAXSIZE), 1, infp);
```

Say at most we need to read 3 times, and after reading 2 times, the remaining stuff in `infp` is less than the size of `MAXSIZE`. How do we determine the size of information at the last read?

Comment: Surely you want `fread(buff, MAXSIZE,1, infp)`?

Comment: fread returns the number of items read. You can just check the return value the third time

Comment: @chux whats wrong with that?

Comment: Note that `sizeof(MAXSIZE) == sizeof(int)`...so you probably don't mean what you wrote.

Answer (score 5):

You can just check the return value of [`fread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fread):

> **Return value**
>
> Number of objects read successfully, which may be less than count if an error or end-of-file condition occurs.

Like this:

```
size_t num = fread(...);
```

---

**P.S.:** as @chux commented, you are actually need to use `fread(buff, MAXSIZE, 1, infp)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

From  `fread` man page

> On success, fread() and fwrite() return the number of items read or written. This number equals the number of bytes transferred only when size is 1. If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).
>   fread() does not distinguish between end-of-file and error, and callers must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred.

[Man fread](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread)